# Does $\operatorname{Log}(z^n)=n\operatorname{Log}(z)+2ik\pi$?

Tags: functions

I study complex functions and I need to prove or disprove that for each $n$ that belongs to the natural numbers, there is a $k$ that belongs to the integers so for every $z$ that belongs to
$\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$ I get  $\operatorname{Log}(z^n)=n\operatorname{Log}(z)+2ik\pi$.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7MjO.png)

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackExchange. Please show your attempt first. You will notice that posting a question without showing an attempt would be ill-received.

Comment: thank you, I added my attempt

Answer (score 2):

$z$ can be expressed as $re^{i\theta}$ and arg $z$ as $\theta$ (I hope you know this form of a complex number. If you don't, a similar argument can be made for the trigonometric form instead). Note that $re^{i\theta}= re^{i\theta+ 2\pi ik}$ for all integers, k because $re^{i\theta+ 2\pi ik} = re^{i\theta} * e^{2\pi i k}$ and $e^{2\pi i k}$ is 1.

This is the part where you had an issue:
$$i\,arg(z^n) = in\,arg\,z$$

Since  $z =  re^{i\theta+ 2\pi ik}=re^{i(\theta+ 2\pi k)}$ note $arg\,z = \theta + 2\pi k$,

$$i\,arg(z^n) = in(\theta + 2\pi k)$$
but $\theta$ is also arg z,
Therefore;

$$i\,arg(z^n) = in(arg z + 2\pi k)$$
$$i\,arg(z^n) = in\, arg z + 2\pi i nk$$
nk is a product of two arbitrary integers and for some k, there will be an integer that can be expressed as such. Let that integer be m. Therefore,
$$i\,arg(z^n) = in\, arg z + 2\pi i m$$ This is equivalent to what you wished to prove. (m is a dummy variable)
The key insight is that $2\pi$ is a full rotation and lands you right back where you started. This means that say $\pi$ was the $\theta$, so would $3\pi$ because  to get to $3\pi$, you would make a full rotation to land back right where $\pi$ was.  I also want to point out that if you didn't show your attempt, I wouldn't know where exactly you had an issue.

Comment: firstly thank you very much for your help. you wrote arg(z) but I refer to the main argument - Arg. so is it still the same?

Comment: Ok. From there it reasonably follows that since $Log(z^n) = ln|z^n| + arg(z^n)$, (and we apply the law of the logarithms and our proof), we will have $Log(z^n) = n\,ln|z| + in\,arg\,z + 2\pi i k$ for some k. Therefore, $Log(z^n) = n(ln|z| + arg\, z) + 2 \pi i k$ Just by the definition of log, the expression in brackets is Log(z). In conclusion, $Log(z^n) = nLog (z) + 2 \pi i k$